# rtmp audio message(0x08) format (mp3)

Tags: audio, format, mp3, message, rtmp

im trying to write a little client for rtmp(audio only). so far i got the communication working (red5 server) but now im stuck with the audio data.

the server is sending in MP3 44KHz 16bit stereo.
i get my Audiomessage which consists of the byte identifying the codec (0x2f) and the audio data which looks for example like this

```
ff:fb:92:64:eb:80:03:98:58:d2:e9:26:1b:7e:5d:e7:4a:1a:19:26:5c:8b:89:07:47:44:98:6b:91:2d:9c:28:b4:33:15:70:82:c9:29:87:8d:e4:8f:31:83:84:7b:e5:82:b5:57:62:00:02:e5:bb:f1:86:15:7a:8f:da:9e:ca:4f:83:9d:0a:c4:56:7b:b3:3d:56:43:ba:2b:28:b8:9d:0c:e1:82:0c:08:36:24:f3:39:67:54:b7:41:d9:8e:ef:36:96:56:22:d2:b9:9f:ae:40:43:8e:ea:39:52:0c:a4:48:25:02:54:91:c7:35:37:2d:be:f2:37:23:61:65:35:d9:0f:aa:18:b4:37:d9:d4:c8:68:21:3c:bd:ea:c1:d0:98:df:eb:96:59:99:88:09:37:36:c3:8b:47:80:64:84:41:ba:35:ea:a6:0a:d6:74:9e:09:f6:a5:d7:3f:1f:53:d8:fb:8d:d9:d3:f8:ee:c7:c1:68:25:25:8e:ae:6a:1c:08:52:9d:58:cf:cf:87:c1:ba:a4:f0:63:76:b0:b4:65:79:1b:3b:21:5f:2f:b5:7a:18:43:af:f7:fd:15:0c:87:c9:73:54:95:22:94:cc:cb:e3:da:4d:e0:f3:8a:95:69:69:eb:32:71:57:08:49:76:e0:f3:84:8c:4b:4c:84:6b:5d:7a:c8:c9:d7:df:d5:e2:68:bb:5f:6c:9f:ba:f4:0a:6c:6e:51:8a:b3:59:9a:07:0c:e4:2a:9d:ec:d1:99:53:48:f2:8b:22:b2:d3:bf:e1:5b:9f:ee:49:9f:2c:ee:63:1f:6f:da:90:e7:65:00:55:99:97:77:b9:e8:97:43:81:fd:32:e4:81:20:d0:78:f5:4f:59:47:39:f2:57:5d:f4:d5:91:48:c9:45:10:52:49:4d:04:87:6b:0e:a5:72:ed:34:74:08:93:5b:8a:54:3a:d9:7e:53:8f:c7:5e:b1:99:f3:55:63:72:49:99:55:3a:b8:0d:73:3b:2a:ea:9a:b5:32:d2:3b:61:c2:4e:e9:56:78:99:14:4a:a7:46:f4:ee:ae:6f:ff:c8:85:2d:07:68:ad:e2:84:dd:0a:bd:2e:93:12:43
```

i dont find a little thing about the data format. as the first byte is always 0xff i assume every chunk of audio data has a little header describing its contents.
the rtmp spec from adobe doesnt loose a single word about the format of the audio message package (just two lines saying its an audio message... wow).

does anyone know the format for the audio messages or at least a source where i find something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Adobe spec doesn't document the elementary stream formats because they are covered in their own documents, and usually quite large. MP3 is covered by ISO/IEC 11172-3.

There is a good rundown available here:
http://www.mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm

Comment: thanks. rtmp uses the mpeg frames in the audiomessage. your link says a file has the same format so if i now write all the frames in a file it should be a valid mp3?

Comment: Yes, It will be playable as a .mp3. Note this may not be true for other codecs. AAC for example would require you to convert the sequence header to an ADTS header and prepend it to every frame before writing it to a file.

Comment: well it kinda works now. the server gives me around 200 KB of data and then stops transmiting without a reason(i dont know why). also the file should be 12 seconds long according to the windows explorer but different media players only play a fraction of a second. when deleting part of the file the sound is changed according to that (audacitys graph display gets shorter). what am i doing wrong? i could also send the mp3 file if that helps someone to help me

Comment: Post a the file. Ill take a look

Comment: i already found the error. seems like i messed something up while parsing the audio messages (i wonder how i managed to even receive anything without crashing). but now i still have the problem that it stops sending data after a while. i read that i have to send an acknowledgement and i also see this rtmp message in wireshark in the original communication from the flashplayer. but it only says i should send it after i received "windowlength" bytes. but neither do i know the windowlength (from wireshark i guess its 125000) nor what to count, everything that ever goes over the socket?

Comment: okay i seem to send the ack correctly. at least it looks pretty much the same. server still stops sending audio data

Comment: solved that too. seems i have to put an additional "Set Buffer Length 1,1000ms" after the play. or any arbitrary buffer length. bigger values seem to mean faster transmission... at least for that server